# Laravel Selecting Relevant Data From DB Based On Arrays

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sql-like, laravel-5.6

I am having a problem with selecting data using the %LIKE% operator.

Currently, I have **two tables called tagging_tags and news**. The **news table has a column called tags** . Below is a picture of what my news table is like:

[image]

Below is a picture of my taggable_tags table:

[image]

My issue is, the data I get in return is not what my intended idea is. If I die dump by visiting the page for 'Honda News 1', I get the results for all the data that has the keyword 'Honda'.

However, 'Honda News 2' and 'Honda News 3' don't return all 3 of the news that has the keyword 'Honda.

Below is my code:

```
    /* relevant articles section */

    // ... my previous code with variable $tag_values (data from tags column in news)

    $i = 0;
    foreach($tag_values as $tagarr){
        $array1[] = $tagarr[0]['name'];
    }

    //$array1 returns array:2 [▼ 0 => "Honda" 1 => "News" ]
    $array2 = Tags::pluck('name')
    ->all();

    //$array2 returns all the arrays in taggable_tags table
    $result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

    //$result finds the arrays that intersect

    $query = News::query();
    foreach($result as $relevant_result){
        $query->where(function ($q) use ($relevant_result){
            $q->where('tags', 'like', '%'.$relevant_result.'%')
                ->orWhere('title', 'like', '%'.$relevant_result.'%');
        });
    }

    $relevant_articles = $query->orderBy('title')->get();
```

I'm hoping somebody could guide me as to how I can get it so that if even one similar keyword is found within the title and tag column under news, it should return the data for the relevant articles.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it myself! :) For anyone having a similar issue, below is my solution:

```
        //... my previous code with variable $tag_values (data from tags column in news)
    $i = 0;
    foreach($tag_values as $tagarr){
        $array1[] = $tagarr[0]['name'];
    }

   // dd($array1);exit;

   $query = News::query();
    foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
        $i++;
        $query->orWhere('tags', 'like', '%'.$value[$i].'%')
        ->orWhere('title','like', '%'.$value[$i].'%');
    }
    $results = $query->take(2)->get();

    dd($results);
```